# error in installing the pip package nb-black

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip

[Click for the error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP7oP.png)

I tried to install nb-black extension for jupyter-lab but facing the above error
My pip version is pip 23.1.2
Python version Python 3.10.11

Comment: As it says in the error description, this is not a problem with pip, it's a problem with the library itself. Evaluating strings with larger or equal to `>=` doesn't seem right. I don't think there's anything we can do here.

Answer (score 0):

As @rasjani said in comment it is bug: https://github.com/dnanhkhoa/nb_black/issues/40

As a temporary work-around you can try downgrade python to 3.10.7

I had similar problem. Try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then `python -m pip install nb-black`.

Comment: sorry I tried but didn't help

Comment: what is your current version of pip?

Comment: @MarcinBaranek Its a bug in the nbblack's setup.py -  https://github.com/dnanhkhoa/nb_black/issues/40